# Access a TFS Server inside a Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, team-foundation-server

I'm running a TFS (2013) Server inside a Windows Server 2008 R2 Hyper-V VM (hosted on Windows 8). Everything seems to be running correctly within the server; however, when I try to connect to the Web URI of the TFS Server, I can't seem to see the server.

The VM is using a static IP and is able to see the network. I can access the VM from the network (i.e. if I type \servername\ into explorer it shows the VM exists)

What can I try / do to diagnose or fix this issue? Is there something specific that I need to do to TFS to cause it to be exposed to the network via a VM?

There server is accessible from within the VM.

Comment: Is the URL accessible on the VM itself?

Comment: Yes, it is  - question updated

Comment: Are you nesting VMs?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: No - not nesting VMs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have disabled the `Firewall`.
Also, disable `Loopbackcheck` on the TFS Server:

1. Click Start, click Run, type `regedit`, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`
3. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click `DWORD` Value.
4. Type `DisableLoopbackCheck`, and then press ENTER.
5. Right-click `DisableLoopbackCheck`, and then click Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type `1`, and then click OK.
7. Exit Registry Editor.
8. Restart the computer.

and Disable `StrictNameChecking`:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and click the following key in the registry:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
3. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following
   registry `DWORD` value: `DisableStrictNameChecking`
4. Right-click `DisableStrictNameChecking`, and then click Modify.
5. In the Value data box, type `1`, and then click OK.
6. Exit Registry Editor.
7. Restart the computer.

Comment: +1 for disabling the firewall. I had a similar issue with my TFS2012 server I had setup as a VMware server. Shutting off the firewall fixed it. Another thing to check, can you access the Web-side of TFS through your browser?

Comment: Yep - it was the firewall!  Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with MichelZ's answer, in my case the problem was that I was trying:

http://MyTfsExperience:8080/tfs/

instead of:

http://MyTfsExperience.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/tfs/

What I mean is that the machine name is not enough. You need (obviously) the complete URL.